# Signal Handler for SIGINT

Tags: c, signals, handler, sigint

I'm supposed to write a C program which handles the first SIGINT with a custom handler, and then reset the default behaviour. My custom SIGINT handler should just print a msg. This is what I wrote:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <strdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(sig)
int sig;
{
    printf("%d received\n",sig);
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    while(1);
    exit(0);
}
```

If I launch it from a shell and then I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the same tab, it works. If I try to send the SIGINT using `kill -INT *process pid*` it just terminates the program, no msg printed. Any idea why?

Comment: "*If I launch it from a shell and then I enter CTRL-C on the same tab, it works.*" not for me. Which "*tab*" are you referring to, BTW?

Comment: Beware: an infinite loop without side-effects is undefined behavior in C. `while (1);` is such an offender, so the compiler is free to do whatever it wants to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `signal` function is not cumulative. You call it twice, so the last one is the good one, using the default behavior (`SIG_DFL`).

You have to just set your handler in `main` and in `handler` to set the new behavior (`signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);`) so that next signal will be default-treated (kill the process).

Note that `signal` may have different behavior on different unix systems, so you should have a look to `sigaction` which is the recommanded way to handle signals.

Comment: It's strange that it seems to work from using Ctrl-C.

Comment: @alk: well, not for me on last xubuntu 64bit. With the given code Ctrl-C directly exits the program, but moving the `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` into `handler()` behave as expected. What OS are you using?

Comment: how sorry, I misunderstood your comment. You mean it seems to work for the requester. Yes, I noticed that but it seems quite illogical so I supposed it was because of a change+not-recompile+run error.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly ecause `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` turns the handler off with respect to the `kill`.  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) has more info about if or when you need that line, and suggests using `sigaction` instead of `signal` for consistent behaviour across platforms:

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = handler;
sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
```